# TinyMCE unsuable after remove from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm having a bit of a problem with TinyMCE if I remove it from the DOM and then add it back in. Basically the Editor becomes unusable.

I've put up a little test case here: http://sprymedia.co.uk/media/misc/tinymce/ . The code to reproduce the issue is fairly simple:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    tinymce.init( {
        selector: '#test'
    } );

    $('button').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#container').remove().appendTo('body');
    } );
} );
```

Is it possible to remove an editor from the DOM and then add it back in? I couldn't see anything in the API about this.

Comment: you would have to reinitialize tinymce on that element when its added back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to reinitialize tinymce after you remove it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#test'
    });

    $('button').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#container').remove().appendTo('body');
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#test'
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/RNdaab)**